# compare two strings in bash

Tags: string, bash, compare

I'd like to compare two strings and then another two strings.
So if $version is not equal to 5 and type is not equal to dbma
OR if $version is not equal to 6 and $type is not equal to dbmy

I can't quite get the syntax right.

```
if [[ "${version}" != "5" ]] &&  [[ "${type}" != "dbma" ]] || [[ "${version}" != "6" ]] &&  [[ "${type}" != "dbmy" ]]
then
   xyz
else
   abc
fi
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: Your question is ambiguous just like your code.  The shell parses this left to right so you have effectively if ((version is not 5 and type is not "dbma") or version is not 6) and type is not "dbmy" ... but you should add similar brackets to your question to specify what you mean.  I'm guessing you want (foo and bar) or (baz and quux) actually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is what you actually mean ...

```
if [[ ($version != 5 && $type != "dbma") || ($version != 6 && type != "dbmy") ]]
```

The `[[` built-in allows parentheses and logical operators within the expression (whereas legacy `[` had neither, and newer versions have `-a` and `-o` for "and" and "or", but no parentheses).